# Zoho Writer document save not working no error

Tags: c#, zoho

I'm working on integrating Zoho Writer into my web app using Zoho Office Integrator.  My web app uses an WebAPI api in c#, .net framework 4.8 and the zoi-csharp-sdk. I am able to open a file from local storage by following the Zoho docs and code examples. The code that opens the doc includes a bit that sets the Save parameters as follows:

```
using Com.Zoho.Util;
using Com.Zoho.Officeintegrator.V1;
using Com.Zoho;
using Com.Zoho.Dc;
using Com.Zoho.API.Authenticator;
using Com.Zoho.API.Logger;
using static Com.Zoho.API.Logger.Logger;

...

    Dictionary<string, object> saveUrlParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    saveUrlParams.Add("templateId", templateId);
    saveUrlParams.Add("filePath", networkPath);
    Dictionary<string, object> saveUrlHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    saveUrlHeaders.Add("Authorization", _context.Token);
    CallbackSettings callbackSettings = new CallbackSettings();
    callbackSettings.Retries = 2;
    callbackSettings.Timeout = 10000;
    callbackSettings.SaveFormat = "docx";
    callbackSettings.HttpMethodType = "post";
    callbackSettings.SaveUrlParams = saveUrlParams;
    callbackSettings.SaveUrlHeaders = saveUrlHeaders;
    if (APIBaseURL.IndexOf("localhost") > -1) APIBaseURL = "https://my url";
    callbackSettings.SaveUrl = APIBaseURL + "api/files/save-zoho-doc";
    createDocumentParams.CallbackSettings = callbackSettings;
```

I have checked that APIBaseURL is accessible from the internet. When I click the Save option in the Writer editor nothing happens. No errors and no logs. The breakpoint in the api call save-zoho-doc is never hit. Here is an excerpt from the api

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("save-zoho-doc")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(string))]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveZohoDoc([FromUri] int templateId, string filePath) {

        System.Web.HttpRequest httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) {
    ...
```

Comment: I may have been having a dns issue.  now I'm getting
Unable to save the document from remote client end. Please try again.  again Zoho docs no help on this

Comment: OK so I found out that the "callbackSettings.SaveUrlParams = saveUrlParams;" doesn't work.  you would think that it would add those things to the query string but it doesn't.  I am able to append my values directly to the url though and that works